# Import error in Google colab with keras_utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2e842b3b11e3> in <cell line: 32>()
     30 from keras.preprocessing import image
     31 import keras.backend as K
---> 32 from keras.utils import layer_utils
     33 from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
     34 from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions

ImportError: cannot import name 'layer_utils' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

When attempting to import keras_utils it returns this error even though I have imported keras, tensorflow, and keras_applications. It might be a version error but I cannot find the updated code on keras.io

Answer (score 0):

The `layer_utils` and `get_file` modules are developmental modules that can no longer be imported like that in `tensorflow 2.x`. You will also face an import error in the next line. In `Tensorflow 2.x`, you have to import `layer_utils` and `get_file` like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
```

Comment: Do you know where I can find the newer versions because there are a few more outdated imports within my code that I am hoping to resolve.

Comment: read their documentation of `tf2.0`